# Cannot free memory in a function

Tags: c, memory, graph

I'm writing a code in which I read some graphs from text file to process it later. I have one function to write graph to memory and second one which uses first one and then operates on this graph. The problem is that I allocate some memory in first function but I don't know where should I free it, because freeing it in first function crashed program, while in second function compiler says there is no such a struct.

```
struct Graph* createGraph(struct edge edges[], int wxk, int l)
{

    // allocate memory for the graph data structure
    //struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    struct Graph* graph = malloc(sizeof *graph);
    graph->head = malloc( l * sizeof *(graph->head) );

    // initialize head pointer for all vertices
    for ( int i = 0; i < wxk; i++ ) {
        graph->head[i] = NULL;
    }

    // add edges to the directed graph one by one
    for ( int i = 0; i < l; i++ )
    {
        // get the source and destination vertex
        int src = edges[i].src;
        int dest = edges[i].dest;
        double weight = edges[i].weight;

        // allocate new node of adjacency list from `src` to `dest`
        struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof *(newNode) );
        struct node* newNode2 = malloc( sizeof *(newNode2));
        newNode->dest = dest;
        newNode->weight = weight;

        newNode->next = NULL;
        if( graph->head[src] == NULL ) {
            graph->head[src] = newNode;
        } else {
            for( newNode2 = graph->head[src]; newNode2->next != NULL; newNode2 = newNode2->next )
                ;
            newNode2->next = newNode;
        }

        struct node* newNode3 = malloc( sizeof *(newNode3) );
        struct node* newNode4 = malloc( sizeof *(newNode4) );
        newNode3->dest = src;
        newNode3->weight = weight;

        newNode3->next = NULL;
        if( graph->head[dest] == NULL ) {
            graph->head[dest] = newNode3;
        } else {
            for( newNode4 = graph->head[dest]; newNode4->next != NULL; newNode4 = newNode4->next )
                ;
            newNode4->next = newNode3;
        }
    }

    return graph;
}
```

Here is first function code, in which I allocate memory to newNode, newNode2, newNode3 and newNode4. When I free this memory at end of this function, program crashes later.

```
void check_graph( char *plik)
{
    FILE *in = fopen( plik, "r");

    struct edge *edges = readfromfile(in);

    int l = getl();
    int wxk = getwxk();
    struct Graph *graph = createGraph( edges, wxk, l);

    struct FIFO queue;
    short int *visited = malloc ( wxk * sizeof (int));
    for( int i = 0; i < wxk; i++)
    {
        visited[i] = 0;
    }
    queue.vertices = (int *) malloc( wxk * sizeof(int) );
    queue.front = 0;
    queue.end = 0;
    
    add_to_queue( &queue, 0);
    visited[0] = 1;
    while( queue.front != queue.end)
    {
        int current_vertex = del_from_queue( &queue);

        struct node *tmp = graph->head[current_vertex];
        while( tmp != NULL)
        {
            int adjVertex = tmp->dest;

            if( visited[adjVertex] == 0)
            {
                visited[adjVertex] = 1;
                add_to_queue( &queue, adjVertex);
            }
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }

    free(queue.vertices); // czyszczenie pamięci
    free(visited);
    free(edges);
    for( int i = 0; i < wxk; i++ )
        free( graph->head[i] );
    free(graph->head);
    free(graph);
}
```

If I try to free the previous memory here, compiler says that names of variables are undeclared

Comment: You can free the memory anywhere, as long as it's no longer needed.

Comment: Why are you allocating memory for `newNode2`? It looks like it's just a temporary variable used for the loop that finds the end of the `head[src]` list. It doesn't need memory of its own.

Comment: The same for `newNode4`.

Comment: haven't looked hard at your code, but sounds like you need to read up [variable scoping](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope). Variables declared in `fun1` aren't accessible in `fun2`. If you want to `malloc` in `fun1` and `free` in `fun2`, then you'll need to use some mechanism to pass them between the functions.

Comment: Please post code samples as a [mcve] and include the exact error message (including the line numbers that generated the error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

Freeing memory should be handled in separate functions that destroy a specific object, one for (adjacency) lists and one for graphs (which calls the adjacency list destroying function). The adjacency list destructor should iterate over a list, freeing nodes as it visits them (note the nodes are freed using the destructor's own local variables, not the `newNodeI` variables in the graph constructor). The graph destructor would be called from `check_graph`. Note that this parallels how creation is handled in the code.

## Longer answer

The program would greatly benefit from following some fundamental design principles. In particular, break up the functions into more basic operations, each of which performs a single task (akin to the Single Responsibility Principle from OOP). When considering the sub-tasks of a task, they should be at the same level and in the same domain (more on this later). Additionally, functions shouldn't be overlong. Repeated code is a candidate for abstraction into a separate function ([Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), as long as it is conceptually a single task. Though the program may not be explicitly object-oriented, some OO conventions can be usefully applied. Variable names should be descriptive.

Start thinking about function names. The sample has `createGraph` and `check_graph`, a mix of naming conventions. This isn't inherently wrong, but naming conventions should only be mixed when each convention is doing something different, and are in different parts of a program. One C convention for naming methods in an OO manner is to use DromedaryCase for class names and [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for method names (as is done in C++), and connect the two with an underscore (basically, [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)) (e.g. `ClassName_methodName`). Extending this, the underscore indicates going down in scope, so nested class methods would be named as: `Outer_Inner_methodName`. Alternatives include using camelCase for class names, or snake case for everything, or snake case but with a double underscore for scope (e.g. `outer_class__inner_class__method_name`). "Private" methods can be indicated with a leading underscore.

The `check_graph` function performs the following sub-tasks:

- opens a file
- causes edges to be read from file
- causes a Graph object to be created
- allocates space for a member field of a queue (`queue.vertices`)
- traverses the graph breadth-first
- examines queue members to determine when it's empty
- destroys the queue member, edges, and Graph

This mixes different levels of tasks (e.g. causing a Graph object to be created (which happens in a different function) but destroying the object itself; creating a part of the queue) and domains (e.g. file I/O, memory management, and graph algorithms), resulting in multiple responsibilities. Reading objects from files should be handled by a component whose responsibility it is to bridge I/O and object creation. Destroying the graph object should be handled by a separate function, a counterpart to `createGraph` (or `Graph_create`, if you use the convention above). This in particular should resolve the issue in question. Queue manipulation should be farmed out to queue functions, [encapsulating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) the operations and data.

The majority of the lines in `check_graph` are concerned with the breadth-first traversal of the graph. This could be the basis for a function that implements the BFS algorithm, taking a callback that's called for each vertex as it's visited. `check_graph` would then call the BFS function.

A sketch of a refactored version:

```
typedef void (*Graph_visitor_t)(Graph_t *graph, int iVertex, void *additional);

/**
 * Breadth-first traversal of a graph
 *
 * visit: a callback, invoked for each vertex when visited
 * pAdditional: additional data passed along to the `visit` function
 */
void Graph_bfs(Graph_t *graph, Graph_visitor_t visit, void *pAdditional) {
    // TODO: detect & handle memory errors
    bool *visited = calloc(sizeof(*visited), graph->nVertices);
    IntQueue_t *queue = IntQueue_create(graph->nVertices);
    
    visit(graph, 0, pAdditional);
    visited[0] = 1;
    IntQueue_push(queue, 0);
    while (! IntQueue_empty(queue)) {
        int current_vertex = IntQueue_pop(queue);
        /* much the same as the original `check_graph` (only 
         * add a call to `visit`)
         */
        // ...
    }

    IntQueue_destroy(queue);
    free(visited);
}

void _Graph_countVisited(Graph_t* graph, int iVertex, int *pnVisited) {
    ++(*pnVisited);
}

// Demonstrates how to use Graph_bfs (check_graph woudl be similar).
void Graph_isConnected(Graph_t *graph) {
    int nVisited = 0;
    Graph_bfs(graph, &_Graph_countVisited, &nVisited);

    return nVisited == graph->nVertices;
}
```

`createGraph` performs the following sub-tasks:

- allocates the graph object & members
- allocates the adjacency list nodes
- traverses adjacency lists
- adds nodes to adjacency lists

Again, some of these tasks are at different levels and should be farmed out (e.g. adjacency list manipulation). The code that manipulates the adjacency list within the loop is also repetitive, and is a great candidate for being moved to another function.

Many of the variable names (e.g. `l`, `wxk`, `newNode3`) aren't very descriptive, leading to some bugs. For example, in `createGraph`, `graph->head` is allocated to hold `l` entries, but `wxk` entries are accessed when initializing it (in this case, the better fix is to use [`calloc`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html) instead of manually initializing all entries to `NULL`). If these variables were name more descriptively, e.g. `nVertices` and `nEdges` (I'm guessing as to purpose), the bug would be more obvious and likely wouldn't have occurred in the first place.

```
void _Graph_addAdjacency(Graph_t *graph, int from, int to, double weight) {
    Node_t *newNode = List_Node_create(to, weight);
    if (graph->head[from] == NULL ) {
        graph->head[from] = newSrcNode;
    } else {
        List_append(graph->head[from], newSrcNode);
    }
}

void _Graph_addEdge(Graph_t *graph, Edge_t *edge) {
    _Graph_addAdjacency(graph, edges[i].src, edges[i].dest, edges[i].weight);
    _Graph_addAdjacency(graph, edges[i].dest, edges[i].src, edges[i].weight);
}

Graph_t* Graph_create(Edge_t edges[], int nEdges, int nVertices) {
    //// allocation
    // TODO: detect & handle memory errors
    Graph_t *graph = malloc(sizeof *graph);
    graph->head = calloc(sizeof *(graph->head), nVertices);
    graph->nVertices = nVertices;

    //// initialization
    // add edges to the directed graph one by one
    for (int i = 0; i < nEdges; i++) {
        // TODO: add error detection
        _Graph_addEdge(graph, edges[i]);
    }

    return graph;
}
```

Rounding out the example are functions to read the graph from the file (`Graph_readFromPath`) and to tie it all together (`main` in this example, though in a larger program it wouldn't be the main function).

```
Graph_t* Graph_readFromPath(const char *fName) {
    FILE *in = fopen(fName, "r");
    
    int nVertices = Count_readFromFile(in);
    int nEdges = Count_readFromFile(in);
    Edge_t *edges = Edges_readFromFile(in, nEdges);

    fclose(in);

    Graph_t* graph = Graph_create(Edge_t edges[], nEdges, nVertices);

    free(edges);
    return graph;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No input file given.");
        return 1;
    }
    const char *fName = argv[1];
    if (access(fname, R_OK)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading input file '%s': %s", fName, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    
    Graph_t *graph = Graph_readFromFile(fName);
    if (! Graph_isConnected(graph)) {
        // ...
    }
    Graph_destroy(graph);

    return 0;
}
```